# I'm not able to debug .NET Core source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, debugging, .net-core

Yes, I know that this question arises from time to time, I have searched for answer on internet, but nothing seems to work right. So I prepared I detailed explanation, accompanied by screenshots, on what I tried to do to be able to follow code execution throught .NET Core source code and what was the result.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 16.8.3, and have created a .NET Core 3.1 web app from template. I changed the code in Startup class to make it crash.

[image]

These are my debug settings (I have no idea weather .NET Framework source stepping has any significance for .NET Core projects):

[image]

So lets run and hit an exception:

[image]

Here I'll choose just to decomplie the source code (there's a link for it on the previous image), to see if this works:

[image]

OK, but I just see the code, can't examine variable and object values. Let's rerun and see if I can get the code by clicking on the symbol server when the exception hits:

[image]

It complains, so let's enable source servers.

[image]

Lets run it again, and hit the exception.

[image]

Now it complains on some kind of exclusion (see *symbol status* column):

[image]

I load all the symbold manually:

[image]

Here I rerun the app, with all the symbols loaded, but when the exception hits I still can't F11 into the .NET Core source:

[image]

*What am I missing to be able to step throught the .NET Core source code?*

Comment: "Enable .Net Framework source stepping"?

Comment: I'm using .NET Core, not .NET Framework. Anyway, I tried that option too, but everything stays the same.

Comment: This shows you how to debug ASP.NET Core source code:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable Source Link? I was able to step into the .NET Core 3.1 source code after doing the following:

- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code" and check "Enable Source Link support" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
  [image]
- Activate the symbol servers in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols
  [image]

I got this information from [Improving Debug-time Productivity with Source Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/) on Microsoft Devblogs.

Answer (score 2):

The exception says that public method `Configure` is missing in `Startup` class. The application did not start properly and that is why debugging does not work.

Comment: The application hit an exception in the .NET Core source sode. I want to see the point where the exception was hit, to examine the context in which it happened. I myself created the situation where the exception would arise, this is just a simplified example of a situation which might arise in a real system.

Comment: You can step into .NET Core source code by enabling Source Link support (I added an answer to describe it in more detail).